# Правильная расстановка знаков в тексте с переплетающимися цитатами

Tags: пунктуация, цитаты

Первая цитата первого цитируемого автора разорвана на части цитатами второго цитируемого автора, цитаты которого в свою очередь разорваны цитатами первого автора, цитаты и того и другого автора как бы переплетены между собой. Но цитата первого автора раскрывает способ изложения мысли в цитате второго автора, раскрывает характер движения мысли последнего. В этом заключается цель и замысел автора соотношения этих цитат, в тексте которого не содержится ни одного слова автора. Надо сказать, что показать соотношение этих цитат иным способом невозможно. Поэтому важно расставить знаки правильно именно в данном тексте. Цитата второго автора выделена курсивом, но курсив здесь не пропечатался. Вопрос в том как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложениях. Ссылки цитирования для упрощения задачи опущены.

Текст таков:
«Особенное»: «сознание» «имеет с другими особенными: «с общим вселенским целым», «к которым оно относится, одну и ту же всеобщность: «и чувство связи». «В то же время ввиду их тождества со всеобщим их разность как таковая всеобща; она есть целокупность: «глубокое, незаменимое утешение». «Особенность»: «сознание с общим вселенским целым», «не только содержит всеобщее»: «и чувство связи», «но и показывает его также через свою единичную определенность»: «глубокое, незаменимое утешение»; «тем самым всеобщее образует собой ту сферу, которую должно исчерпать особенное».

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно.

Comment: У двоеточия нет такой функции.